# Error while setting up SASL/SCRAM in kafka on windows

Tags: apache-kafka, sasl-scram

I am running kafka on windows. I am trying to setup SASL/SCRAM authentication. [This](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/authentication_sasl_scram.html#kafka-sasl-auth-scram) is the link I am following for setting up SASL/SCRAM. On running `bin/kafka-configs --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --add-config 'SCRAM-SHA-256=[iterations=8192,password=alice-secret],SCRAM-SHA-512=[password=alice-secret]' --entity-type users --entity-name alice` I get the error

> Unknown Dynamic configuration: Set('SCRAM-SHA-256)

Does anybody know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Remove quotes ' from configuration SCRAM.

`bin/kafka-configs --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --add-config SCRAM-SHA-256=[iterations=8192,password=alice-secret],SCRAM-SHA-512=[password=alice-secret] --entity-type users --entity-name alice`